# How to set the display text of DT::datatable pagination buttons to custom strings?

Tags: javascript, r, dt

### Problem

In visualizing my data, I need to output a DT::datatable.

Requirement 1 for the datatable is that the table displayed is divided into pages, where different pages contain different subsets of the data.

In my example here below I use the mtcars dataset, divide it into 3 subsets (cars with 4 cylinder, cars with 6 cylinders and cars with 8 cylinders) and display the three subsets on different pages of the DT::datatable (on pages 1, 2 and 3 respectively).

Requirement 2 is that the user can move to a page by the click of a button. By using the default pagination functionality provided by DT::datatable, we can achieve this behavior by setting paging=TRUE in the options list when instantiating the DT::datatable. This way, we get pagination buttons. In my case, I set pagingType="numbers", since I only need a button for each page, i.e. no "Previous" or "Next" buttons.

Now to the problem.

Is there a way to change the default text in the pagination buttons from "1", "2", "3" etc to a custom text? For example, in our mtcars example I would like to change "1", "2", "3" to "4 cyl", "6 cyl" and "8 cyl".

### Further background and what I've already tried

The default pagination buttons ("1", "2", "3", ...) display and work properly, but when I try to change their display text I always run into an issue of some sort.

Here are some of my failed attempts:

- setting the "language" attribute of the DT::datatable options (you can find this failed attempt in a commented section in my example code below),
- setting the initComplete attribute to a (very naïve) JavaScript function supposed to change the display text of the pagination buttons (can also be found in a commented section in the example code).

I assume the problem can be easily solved with the right JavaScript knowledge, something I sadly do not possess.

The end product is actually an R-powered custom visual in Microsoft Power BI. Hence the need for using a data object which can be displayed as HTML. Since the end product is a custom visual in Power BI, I would prefer not to get any additional external packages involved.

Help greatly appreciated!

```
require("DT")

data("mtcars")

# In our example, let's only look at Model Name and Number of Cylinders.
tmp_df <- data.frame("Model"=rownames(mtcars), "cyl"=mtcars$"cyl", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Subset into 3 subsets, one for each possible
four_cyl <- tmp_df[tmp_df$cyl==4,]
six_cyl <- tmp_df[tmp_df$cyl==6,]
eight_cyl <- tmp_df[tmp_df$cyl==8,]

# For the sake of convenience, let all subsets have the same number of rows.
four_cyl <- four_cyl[c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(1, 2)]
six_cyl <- six_cyl[c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(1, 2)]
eight_cyl <- eight_cyl[c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(1, 2)]

# We want all pages in our DT::datatable to have the same number of rows.
page_length <- nrow(four_cyl)

# Bind the subsets of equal length together. This way it's easy to display 
# the different subsets on different pages in the DT::datatable.
output_df <- rbind(four_cyl, six_cyl, eight_cyl)

dt <- datatable(output_df,
                width = '400px',
                escape=FALSE, 
                rownames=FALSE,
                options=list(dom='rtp',
                             pagingType="numbers",
                             # language = list(
                             #   paginate = list(first = '4 cyl', second = '6 cyl', third = '8 cyl')
                             # ),
                             pageLength=page_length,
                             paging=TRUE,
                             lengthChange=TRUE,
                             ordering=FALSE,
                             info=FALSE,
                             searching=FALSE,
                             scrollX=FALSE,
                             columnDefs=list(list(width='60px', className='dt-center', targets='_all'))
                             #,
                             # initComplete = JS(
                             #   "function(settings, json) {",
                             #   "$(\"body\").children().each(function () {
                             #       $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(\">1<\", \">4 cyl<\") );
                             #       $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(\">2<\", \">6 cyl<\") );
                             #       $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(\">3<\", \">8 cyl<\") );
                             #     });",
                             #   "}"
                             # )
                ),
                class='cell-border stripe') %>% formatStyle(
                  columns = colnames(output_df), target='row', lineHeight='60%'
                )

print(dt)
```

### Desired output

A DT::datatable where the text of the pagination buttons has been replaced with "4 cyl", "6 cyl" and "8 cyl". Alternatively, any other approach where different subsets of the data are displayed on different pages of the DT::datatable and we can easily switch through the different views using buttons with custom texts.